# Solving a system of mass, spring, damper and Coulomb friction

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods, ode

Consider the system below:

```
            
        Fig.1 - Mass, spring, damper and Coulomb frction (image courtesy of Wikimedia).
```

with a dynamic equation of:

where `Ff` is the Amontons-Columb friction defined as:

and consequently, the `no-slip` condition is defined as

Following [this example](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/02/02/Solving-a-second-order-ode/), I have a vague code in mind which I don't know how to complete:

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

m = 1.0
k = 2.0
c = 0.1
mus = 0.3
muk = 0.2
g = 9.8
vf = 0.01

def eq(X, t, Xi):
  Ff = k * (Xi[0] - X[0]) + c * (Xi[1] - X[1]) # - m * dydt

  if np.abs(X[1]) < vf and np.abs(Ff) < mus * m * g :
    Ff = k * (Xi[0] - X[0]) + c * (Xi[1] - X[1]) # - m * dydt
  else:
    Ff = -np.sign(X[1]) * muk * m * g
    pass

  dxdt = X[1]
  dydt = (k * (Xi[0] - X[0]) + c * (Xi[1] - X[1]) - Ff) / m
  return [dxdt, dydt]

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
Xi0 = np.piecewise(t, [t < 1, t >= 1], [0, 1])
X0 = [0, 0]
sol = odeint(eq, X0, t)
```

where `Xi0` is a step function. My main issue is that when I want to define `Ff` it depends on `dydt` which is to be defined later in that scope!

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the most canonical way to numerically solve this system. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure the given expression of `F_f` is correct. Do you have a source for this? Often solid friction is considered in a static system. It's actually more a question about physics than python code... I would say that the dynamic equation needs to be solved only in case of slippage, otherwise the equation is dX/dt=(acceleration=0, velocity=0)...

Comment: I think I have implemented it correctly in the below posts. the code in this post had some issues.

Comment: @Foad If the implementations in the answers below are better than the ones in the question, please edit the question to include them (or a shorter version of them, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna put a simplified/temporary solution here till someone comes with a better one:

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = 0.2
k = 2.0
c = 0.1
mus = 0.3
muk = 0.2
g = 9.8
vf = 0.01
v0 = 0.0
t1 = 10
sign = lambda x: np.tanh(100*x)

def Xi(t):
  if t < 1 :
    return 0
  else:
    return 1

vXi = np.vectorize(Xi)

def eq(X, t, Xi):
  Ff = k * (Xi(t) - X[0])

  if np.abs(X[1]) < vf and np.abs(Ff) < mus * m * g :
    Ff = k * (Xi(t) - X[0])
  else:
    Ff = sign(X[1]) * muk * m * g

  d2x = (k * (Xi(t) - X[0]) - Ff) / m
  return [X[1], d2x]

t = np.linspace(0, t1, 1000)
X0 = [v0, 0]
sol = odeint(func = eq, y0 = X0, t = t, args = (Xi, ), mxstep = 50000, atol = 1e-5)

plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0], 'r-', label = 'Output (x(t))')
plt.plot(t, vXi(t), 'b-', label = 'Input (xi(t))')
plt.ylabel('values')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

and the result is:

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470401/4999991), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32992982/4999991) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843544/4999991) posts to write the code. I ignored damping and inertia to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is just to use a for loop and calculate steps sequentially:

```py
Y = np.piecewise(t, [t < t2, t >= t2], [0, 1])
dY = np.insert(np.diff(Y) / np.diff(t), 0 , v0, axis = 0)
X = np.zeros((steps,))
dX = np.zeros((steps,))
dX[0] = v0
ddX = np.zeros((steps,))
Ff = np.zeros((steps,))
# FS = np.zeros((steps,))
dt = t1 / (steps - 1)

for ii in range(1, steps):
  X[ii] = X[ii - 1] + dt * dX[ii - 1]
  dX[ii] = dX[ii - 1] + dt * ddX[ii - 1]
  Ff[ii] = k * (Y[ii] - X[ii]) #+ c * (dY[ii] - dX[ii])
  if not (np.abs(dX[ii]) < vf and np.abs(Ff[ii]) < mus * m * g) :
    Ff[ii] = np.sign(dX[ii]) * muk * m * g
  ddX[ii] = (k * (Y[ii] - X[ii]) - Ff[ii]) / m
```

the result is shown as green in below plot:

I also changed the `vf` to `0.001`. The results are different from `odeint` for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

Writing the equations of such a system is not obvious. And solving it is also not easy.

If the Python constraint can be released, I would suggest using [OpenModelica](https://www.openmodelica.org/) to solve this problem. In the modelica library of components, you have the element

```
.Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.MassWithStopAndFriction
```

which can be used to model dry friction.