# Runge–Kutta methods for ODE integration in Python with additional constraints

Tags: python, math, physics, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I have a question on solving second order differential equations using RK4, considering additional constraints on the first derivative. I am doing the example shown [here](https://perso.crans.org/besson/notebooks/Runge-Kutta_methods_for_ODE_integration_in_Python.html) with some modifications

> *θ′′(t) + b θ′(t) + c sin(θ(t)) = 0*

The additional constraint is:

> when *θ<sub>i</sub>* *θ<sub>(i+1)</sub>*<0, then *θ′<sub>(i+1)</sub>*=0.9*θ′<sub>i</sub>*,

where i is the steps of t, i+1 is one step after i. In the real world, it says when the direction of displacement reverses, its velocity is reduced to 90%.

Vectorially if *y*(*t*) = (*θ*(*t*), *ω*(*t*)), then the equation is *ẏ* = *f*(*t*,*y*), where *f*(*t*,*y*) = (*y*₂(*t*), −*by*₂(*t*) − cos(*y*₁(*t*))).

In this problem, how should I modify the code if I want to add constraints on *ω* or θ′(t) (which are the same thing)?
Here is my code which didn't work. The additional condition makes θ′ non-continuous. The following "homemade" solution cannot update θ′ properly. I am new to Python and this is my first StackOverflow post. Any guidance is much appreciated.

```py
def rungekutta4(f, y0, t, args=()):
    n = len(t)
    y = np.zeros((n, len(y0)))
    y[0] = y0
    for i in range(n - 1):
        h = t[i+1] - t[i]
        if y[i][0]*y[i+1][0]<0:
            k1 = f(y[i], t[i], *args)
            k2 = f(y[i] + k1 * h / 2., t[i] + h / 2., *args)
            k3 = f(y[i] + k2 * h / 2., t[i] + h / 2., *args)
            k4 = f(y[i] + k3 * h, t[i] + h, *args)
            y[i+1] = y[i] + (h / 6.) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)*0.9
        else:
            k1 = f(y[i], t[i], *args)
            k2 = f(y[i] + k1 * h / 2., t[i] + h / 2., *args)
            k3 = f(y[i] + k2 * h / 2., t[i] + h / 2., *args)
            k4 = f(y[i] + k3 * h, t[i] + h, *args)
            y[i+1] = y[i] + (h / 6.) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)        
    return y
```

Comment: Your last modification does not make sense. In the branching condition you use the future value `y[i+1]` that you are just going to compute. And what is the difference between the branches, are the functions supposed to be different, or the parameter tuple?

Comment: Your condition does not make much sense in either formulation. The first test is for the angle to be zero, the pendulum being vertical. Getting additional friction on that position can be arranged physically. But would it not be better to just have a position-dependent friction coefficient? In the second formulation you say that at the moment where the velocity is zero you want to reduce it by 10%. But 10% of zero is still zero.

Comment: Hi Lutz, thanks for your comments. This is not a typical pendulum problem. It is for rocking/impact where the position theta can be positive or negative. Eveytime its position changes between positive and negative, I want to reduce its energy by reducing velocity by 10%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current formulation and taking the idea that each time the pendulum passes the vertical position its velocity is reduced by 10%, this can be approximately arranged as

```py
    for i in range(n - 1):
        h = t[i+1] - t[i]
        y[i+1] = RK4step(f,t[i],y[i],h, args)
        if y[i+1,0]*y[i,0] < 0: y[i+1,1] *= 0.9
    return y
```

that is, first compute the new value and then apply the condition. The time step should be small enough that the angle only changes a few degrees. For larger time steps you would have to split the step containing the zero crossing, using some root finding method like the secant method to find a more accurate time of the root.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! You earned my respect. The problem is solved using the following code to update the first derivative if y[i+1,0]*y[i,0] < 0: y[i+1,1] *= 0.9

Answer (score 1):

Unless I completely misunderstand you, what you want is a simple case distinction in *f:* Mathematically, you have *f₂*(*t*,*y*) = −*by*₂(*t*) − cos(*y*₁(*t*)) if *θ*<sub>*i*</sub>²−1 = *y*₁(*t*)²−1 < 0 and 0.9·(*y*₂−1) otherwise. This is all still only a dependency of *f* on *y,* which can simply implemented programming-wise.

For example, you could define:

```py
def f(y):
    θ = y[0]
    ω = y[1]
    return [
        θ,
        -b*ω-cos(θ) if θ**2<1 else 0.9*(ω-1)
    ]
```

While this may work as it is, you may face problems due to *f* not being continuous (or having a continuous derivative), in particular if you want to use more advanced integrators with step-size control instead of your homebrewed one.
To avoid this, replace the `if`–`else` construct with a (sharp) sigmoid. For more details on this, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843544/2127008).

Comment: The problem hasn't been solved. Maybe I wasn't clear about my questions. I made some edits and hope you can have another look when you get some time. Thank you!